# Twitter Bootstrap - Giving thumbnail caption a minimum number of lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel in Bootstrap that displays 4 columns of thumbnails. [Here's](http://nisusa.com/new/www/index1.php) the carousel in question. If you move to the third page, you can see that the container increases in height in order to accommodate the contents of the thumbnail captions. I've been trying many things such as setting bottom margins, min heights, etc. to get the position of the "View Details" button constant across the entire carousel.

My question is what is the best way to approach this issue? I was thinking somehow making the thumbnail caption height a minimum of 4 or so lines, but I tried that(probably the wrong way) to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add

```
.caption h4 {
    min-height: 2.2em; /* 2 lines as line-height is 1.1 */
}
```

I get all "View details" at the same level. However, that obviously doesn't treat the problem of captions being even higher. It only works if no caption is higher in fact. (But it IS ok, *if you know for sure nothing is going to be higher than your multiple*.)

So, instead I apply this little bit of CSS to put a limit from the other side.

```
.caption h4 {
    max-height: 4.4em;  /* 4 lines as line-height is 1.1 */
    height: 4.4em;      /* making it a multiple allows usage of overflow */
    overflow: hidden;   /* without cutting a line in the middle */
}
```

If you want to set a max-height equal to the height of the highest of captions **dynamically**, than you would have to use a little bit of JS:

```
(function(d) {
    var captions = d.querySelectorAll('.caption h4'),
        height = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
        height = Math.max(height, captions[i].offsetHeight); // or clientHeight depends on you box model
    }

    var style = d.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '.caption h4 { max-height: '+ height +'px; height: '+ height +'px; }'; // they don't need overflow as none of them can overflow;
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

})(document);
```

You add this script at the end of body, so that the DOM is already loaded (or somehow trigger it onload).

**Important**: this snippet is not supported by older browsers because of the `querySelectorAll`.

And that does the trick when I run it on your site.